# Query with date in Android Room

Tags: java, date, android-room

I have a table `todo_db` with a column `dueDate` and I want to run a query to select all where `dueDate` is like a given date.

I wrote this query in my Dao

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM todo_db WHERE dueDate LIKE :givenDate")
    List<todoEnt> getGivenDate(Date givenDate);
```

To use it I call for an instance of the database, I use an instance of Calendar and use getTime()

```
Calendar c;
Date dateToday;

c = Calendar.getInstance();
dateToday = c.getTime();

datalist = db.Maindao().getGivenDate(dateToday);
```

I have tried with

```
SELECT * FROM todo_db WHERE dueDate = :givenDate
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM todo_db WHERE dueDate < (strftime('%s', 'now'))
```

I appreciate any help you can give. Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**

I have TypeConverter and dueDate is Date

```
@Entity(tableName = "todo_db")
public class todoEnt {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    public String todoTitle;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    public String todoDescription;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "dueDate")
    public Date todoDueDate;

}
```

```
public class Convertors {
    @TypeConverter
    public Date fromTimeStamp(Long value){
        return value == null ? null : new Date(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public Long dateToTimestamp(Date date){
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the datatype of dueDate? You might need to have a Type Converter: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/TypeConverter

Comment: @ObiObi It is Date, I have a TypeConverter. :D

Comment: You should also show your entity class, todoEnt.

Comment: `strftime('%s', 'now')` returns _seconds_ since Epoch.  You need to multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds for a valid comparison with `dueDate`.

Comment: @ObiObi, I have updated the info. :D

Comment: @BobSnyder Thank you, now I can get the dates that are bigger than or less than. But how I compare the dates? I want a list with the dueDate equals I date a give.

Comment: It's not clear how closely you want a `dueDate` to match the current time.  Same millisecond, second, minute, hour or day?  I'm guessing you want same day. Is that right?

Comment: @BobSnyder Yes, same day, please.

Answer (score 2):

use long instead of date in method. remember that internally room is storing the date as a long.

so in your DAO you should have something like ...

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM todo_db WHERE dueDate = :givenDateInLong")
getGivenDate(long givenDateInLong)
```

then your code will be like ...

```
Calendar c;
Date dateToday;

c = Calendar.getInstance();
dateToday = c.getTime();
long dateTodayInLong = dateToday.getTime();

datalist = db.Maindao().getGivenDate(dateTodayInLong);
```